# Migrating a CA between trusted forests

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority

I know it is possible to migrate a CA between Domains within an Active Directory forest (as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742388(WS.10).aspx), but is it possible to migrate a CA from one trusted forest to another?  Any caveats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is not supported as per: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742466(WS.10).aspx